# Cloud-init mount device in already mounted directory

Tags: centos7, cloud-init

Hello I would like to mount the following:

```
disk_setup:
  /dev/vdb:
    table_type: mbr
    layout: auto
  /dev/vdc:
    table_type: mbr
    layout: auto

fs_setup:
  - label: test
    filesystem: ext4
    device: /dev/vdb
  - label: test2
    filesystem: ext4
    device: /dev/vdc

mounts:
 - [ /dev/vdb, /var, "auto", "defaults", "0", "2"]
 - [ /dev/vdc, /var/log, "auto", "defaults", "0", "2"]
```

but /var/log never gets mounted on CentOS 7 using the setup with terraform...
and I sadly cannot figure out why. As soon as the Server is started I can manually mount the disk tho. -> Therefore I assume the setup works but the mounting fails potentially bc vdc only succeeds if vdb is done.

Any advices would be great! Ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to replace `mounts` with the cmd equivalents:

```
runcmd: 
 - mount /dev/vdc /var/log
 - mount /dev/vdb /var
```